# problem with python code of writting recognition

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have got a python code from githab which is used for recognizing a hand written pcture (ex. a number) but there is proble. when I run the code an error about line 4 which is " label = int(image_file_name[-5:-4])" appears. The exact description of the error is :"ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'y'". Moreover, I have a 28*28 pixel photo which I want to be read by the code.

```
import imageio
import glob

import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot
our_own_dataset = []
for image_file_name in glob.glob('my_own_images/2828_my_own_?.png'):
    print ("loading ... ", image_file_name)
    # use the filename to set the correct label
    label = int(image_file_name[-5:-4])
    # load image data from png files into an array
    img_array = imageio.imread(image_file_name, as_gray=True)
    # reshape from 28x28 to list of 784 values, invert values
    img_data  = 255.0 - img_array.reshape(784)
    # then scale data to range from 0.01 to 1.0
    img_data = (img_data / 255.0 * 0.99) + 0.01
    print(numpy.min(img_data))
    print(numpy.max(img_data))
    # append label and image data  to test data set
    record = numpy.append(label,img_data)
    print(record)
    our_own_dataset.append(record)
    pass
```

Comment: Welcome to SO; "*doesn't work for me*" is not a helpful description for possible respondents, please update your question (not in the comments) with more details about the exact problem you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

image_file_name is a string and you are trying to convert it into int. That is what the error means.i think the indexes when filtering in that string are wrong.

it should be int(9) but you got int('y')

Comment: when I want to plot it by "matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(our_own_dataset[3][1:].reshape(28,28), cmap='Greys', interpolation='None')" I encounter an error " list index out of range"

Comment: i think indexing that you are doing in our_own_dataset is wrong, before doing this try to do print(len(our_own_dataset)) and print(len(our_own_dataset[3]))